# How to show same product attribute sort on compare page Magento

Tags: magento, sorting, attributes, compare, html

i am not sure why the sorting of a product attribute on compare page is not working same as on product page. Like on product page the atribute sort is

> **on product page**

```
1 name 
2 new attribute 
3 new attribute1 
4 color
```

but on comapre page when i am comp[aring the 2 products has same attributes the attribute sort order becomes

**on compare page**

```
1 name
2 color
3 new attribute
4 new attribute1
```

I have googled a lot to find answer but unable to find. Please help me to fix this issue.

Below are the functions which i find

```
public function getComparableAttributes()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_comparableAttributes)) {
            $this->_comparableAttributes = array();
            $setIds = $this->_getAttributeSetIds();
            if ($setIds) {
                $attributeIds = $this->_getAttributeIdsBySetIds($setIds);

                $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
                    ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute')))
                    ->join(
                        array('additional_table' => $this->getTable('catalog/eav_attribute')),
                        'additional_table.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id'
                    )
                    ->joinLeft(
                        array('al' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute_label')),
                        'al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = ' . (int) $this->getStoreId(),
                        array('store_label' => $this->getConnection()->getCheckSql('al.value IS NULL', 'main_table.frontend_label', 'al.value'))
                    )
                    ->where('additional_table.is_comparable=?', 1)
                    ->where('main_table.attribute_id IN(?)', $attributeIds);
                $attributesData = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
                if ($attributesData) {
                    $entityType = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY;
                    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                        ->importAttributesData($entityType, $attributesData);
                    foreach ($attributesData as $data) {
                        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                            ->getAttribute($entityType, $data['attribute_code']);
                        $this->_comparableAttributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
                    }
                    unset($attributesData);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_comparableAttributes;
    }

/**
 * Load Comparable attributes
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Compare_Item_Collection
 */
public function loadComparableAttributes()
{
    $comparableAttributes = $this->getComparableAttributes();
    $attributes = array();
    foreach ($comparableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $attributes[] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    }
    $this->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);

    return $this;
}
```

bUt i cant understand how to filter it by sort order .Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

check the modifications in function below: 
the file used is **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Compare/Item/Collection.php** 
But this is not the best way to do it. you need to override it as per Magento Standards.
I am working on it, will update shortly.

```
public function getComparableAttributes()
{
    if ($this->_comparableAttributes === null) {
        $this->_comparableAttributes = [];
        $setIds = $this->_getAttributeSetIds();
        if ($setIds) {
            $attributeIds = $this->_getAttributeIdsBySetIds($setIds);

            $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
                ['main_table' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')]
            )->join(
                ['additional_table' => $this->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute')],
                'additional_table.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id'
            )->joinLeft(
                ['al' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_label')],
                'al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = ' . (int)$this->getStoreId(),
                [
                    'store_label' => $this->getConnection()->getCheckSql(
                        'al.value IS NULL',
                        'main_table.frontend_label',
                        'al.value'
                    )
                ]
            )
                    ->joinLeft( //add sort order to sort the attributes as per backend sort.  -- Abid
                ['as' => $this->getTable('eav_entity_attribute')],
                'as.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id'
            )
                    ->where(
                'additional_table.is_comparable=?',
                1
            )->where(
                'main_table.attribute_id IN(?)',
                $attributeIds
            )
                    ->order('as.sort_order') //sort by sort_order -- Abid
                    ;
            $attributesData = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
            if ($attributesData) {
                $entityType = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY;
                $this->_eavConfig->importAttributesData($entityType, $attributesData);
                foreach ($attributesData as $data) {
                    $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $data['attribute_code']);
                    $this->_comparableAttributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
                }
                unset($attributesData);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->_comparableAttributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On product page attributes are sorted like in attribute set.

On compare page attributes are not sorted at all.
You can rewrite function **getComparableAttributes** in class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Compare_Item_Collection** and implement your own sort logic.

But note, that this function differs in different Magento versions. You can try to use free extension [ET Advanced Compare](http://shop.etwebsolutions.com/eng/et-advancedcompare.html) or take part of code from this extension (code is available on bitbucket.org. link i on extension page)

Comment: i am using a enterprise edition and the extension is not compatible with this version

Comment: You can take this changed function from AdvancedCompare extension (https://bitbucket.org/etws/et_advancedcompare/src/6bed82bccbbcc4fad981784fb518d58cb07ce0bf/install/app/code/community/ET/AdvancedCompare/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Compare/Item/Collection.php?at=master)

Comment: yes i already got it from there and it works thanks for the help